# Silverlight 3 namespace missing in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I am putting a silverlight 3 [video](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/dataform-control/) to practice in silverlight 4 as my pc doesnt have SL 3. 
This however doesnt seem to work the same way for Silverlight4.

1.) I couldnt find the dataform control in the same namespace System.Windows.Controls as mentioned in the video, had to get it by drag-dropping from exp. blend 4.

2.) The dataform control that loads when I run the application doesnt have the save button or the edit link.

3.) Also, the bindable property set to oneway doesnt make the field read-only.

Is this by design or do I need to reinstall something. My win7 pc does not have VS2008 IDE or Silverlight 3 tools/sdk/toolkit installed, only VS2010 with Silverlight 4 and Expression blend 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataForm` control is the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace but its found in the `System.Windows.Controls.DataForm.Toolkit.dll` assembly.  However this is the same whether you are using the latest Nov09 Toolkit (for Silverlight 3) or Apr10 Toolkit (for Silverlight 4).

The video is aging a little now, I think it was the Oct09 toolkit which introduced the .Toolkit suffix for assemblies in the toolkit and that video doesn't show that.

Since `DataForm` is still at Preview quality you can expect that a number of things may have changed about how it behaves since the video was created.